# monitoring linux server sockets or files

Tags: linux, sockets, tomcat, netstat, ulimit

I have the famous `socketexception too many open files` bug.
Iam running an apache http server, tomcat server and a mysql database on my server.

I checked the limit of open files with `ulimit -n` that gave me 1024.
If i want to check how many files are opened by `lsof -u tomcat`, it gives me 5
same for mysql. I not sure what the problem is.. but i have also a readlink permission denied.

i want to monitor my socket connections and opened files on my server. I thought about using the decribed linux commands in a shell script and send them per mail to me.

The other option i think is using `netstat` and count maybe the connections.. but its loading very slowly and is giving me getnameinfo fail.

what would be the better command to monitor the bug i have`?

EDIT:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';
    Variable_name Value
    Com_ha_open 0
    Com_show_open_tables 0
    Open_files 8
    Open_streams 0
    Open_table_definitions 87
    Open_tables 64
    Opened_files 673
    Opened_table_definitions 87
    Opened_tables 628
    Slave_open_temp_tables 0



    SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';

    Variable_name Value
    have_openssl DISABLED
    innodb_open_files 300
    open_files_limit 2000
    table_open_cache 64



    SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%'

    character_set_connection latin1
    collation_connection latin1_swedish_ci
    connect_timeout 10 
    init_connect 
    max_connect_errors 10
    max_connections 400
    max_user_connections 0


    SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%';

    Variable_name Value
    Aborted_connects 1
    Connections 35954
    Max_used_connections 102
    Ssl_client_connects 0
    Ssl_connect_renegotiates 0
    Ssl_finished_connects 0
    Threads_connected 11
```

Comment: With MySQL Client logon, post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%'; and C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%'; and D) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%'; please.

Comment: could you formulate a nice answer and format it please? also maybe some notes to the commands . TY ;)

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%open%'

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%';

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%';

Comment: So we know the values your system is running with to determine if there are any excesses or deficiencies.  To avoid overfitting or underfitting.

Comment: @WilsonHauck can you check the sql queries? and  give me an advice? Thank you

Comment: Checked your posting and answer posted on May 30, 2020 for your consideration.  Did it help?

Comment: yes all the points you mentioned where very useful to debug the problem.

Comment: Great, Thank you. I wish you continued progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check ulimit values with 'ulimit -a' to determine capacity of Open Files.
From OS Command Prompt, ulimit -n 8192 and press enter to enable more Open Files dyamically.
To make this change persist across OS restart, the next URL can be your guide.

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Where their example is for 500000 capacity, use 8192 for your system, please.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
thread_cache_size=100  # to support your max_used_connections of 102
max_user_connections=400  # from 0 to match max_connections requested
table_open_cache=800  # from 64 to reduce Opened_tables count
innodb_open_files=800  # from 300 to match table_open_cache requested
```

Implementing these details should avoid 'too many open files' message. For additional assistance, view profile, Network profile for contact information and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.